# Which Ubuntu should i install in order to install latest LTS version?

Tags: 14.04

According to the release schedule, the latest long-term support version will be：

18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver 2018-04-26[280] 2023-04 TBA

2018-04-26. If I want to be able to upgrade to 18.04 LTS in April, right now what version should I install? 16.04 LTS or 17.10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade from one LTS version to another LTS version is supported. So installing 16.04 should be ok.